# Adding websocket support to JBOSS 7 using Tyrus (WebSocket reference implementation)

Tags: jboss, websocket

I recently came across Tyrus (https://tyrus.java.net/), which is the reference implementation of JSR-356 (Java API for WebSockets), and also the WebSocket implementations used in GlassFish app server. Since i have a web app that would greatly benefit from using web sockets i'm thinking about using Tyrus to add web socket support. The problem is that my app is deployed on JBOSS - version 7.2.0 (EAP 6.1 Alpha).

So my question is - has anyone tried this before and is there a reason why JBOSS 7 + Tyrus combination shouldn't work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, JBOSS includes its own websocket implementation, which might clash with Tyrus (there are some scanning processes which might reveal classes from other implementations and that might get messy). So you might need to remove that jar from your modules directory and maybe put Tyrus there (or include it in your war file, the effect should be the same).

In general, Tyrus requires only Servlet 3.1 API to be implemented - if this condition is met, it should work.